# Bulk renaming files

Tags: regex, batch-file, grep, file-rename

So I have a series of files with the following format Their real file name followed by the date.

```
file_1_12DEC2011.pdf
file_2_12DEC2011.pdf
file_3_12DEC2011.pdf
file_4_12DEC2011.pdf
file_5_12DEC2011.pdf
```

I am trying to figure out How I can Increment the day by one day. For instance, this would be my desired result.

```
file_1_13DEC2011.pdf
file_2_13DEC2011.pdf
file_3_13DEC2011.pdf
file_4_13DEC2011.pdf
file_5_13DEC2011.pdf
```

Comment: Is the date always `12DEC2011` for all your files? If yes, a RegEx based renamed can do the trick. But if not, you need to write some code. Regular expression would not be able to change `31JAN2011` to `01FEB2011` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it safely, `echo` before `mv`:

```
for i in file_[1-5]_12DEC2011.pdf; do
    mv $i ${i/12/13}
done
```

To do it quickly, use the `rename` command:

```
$ rename 's/12/13/' file_[1-5]_12DEC2011.pdf
```

**UPDATE:**
You can use `awk` to generate new file name, and put it in those command above.

```
for i in *_*.pdf; do
    mv $i `echo $i | awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{sub(/[0-9]+/, $NF+1, $NF)}1'`
done
```

Comment: If the date is ALWAYS `12DEC2011` this should work. If not RegEx cannot help in this situation.

Comment: Just to fully understand this is a regular expression so say I had files going up into the 5 digits it would be possible to say [0-9]+

Answer (score 1):

Yoy may try this .BATch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
   set name=%%~Nf
   set day=!name:~-9,2!
   set /A day=1!day! %% 100 + 1
   if !day! lss 10 set day=0!day!
   ECHO ren %%f !name:~0,-9!!day!!name:~-7!
)
```

Test the file and, if the result is OK, delete the ECHO part in ren command.

This file should work with any name and any number, as long as the last 9 characters of the file name be the date in DDMMMYYYY format as shown above.